# Training Error & Convergence to True Error

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, pattern-recognition, learning-theory

I Take some online class for Machine Learning. one of teacher say this sentence.

if we have m data points, the training error converges to the true error as m → ∞.

i thought, this  sentence not always correctly. i think when we assume that the data points are i.i.d this sentence becomes true. but in general it's false.

any tutorial for clarity on  my thought and Real ML  ?

Answer (score 0):

Statistical machine learning always assumes that the data points all come from the same distribution and are i.i.d.

If they weren't, the machine learning task would be hopeless.  Imagine if there were some crazy correlation where the 1000th data point has a crazy different distribution (maybe correlated to all 999 prior data points in a crazy way).  Now imagine trying to train a model on the first 999 points, and then use the learned model to classify the 1000th data point.  There would be no hope of success.

So machine learning can only be used when all of the points have the same distribution, iid.